# When password doesn't comply with if statements doesn't return back to raw_input

Tags: python, passwords, raw-input

Function check whether user's password qualifies, as far as alphanumeric characters, 10 characters length min, and lower and uppercase characters.

```
def is_good_password(password):
    count_upper, count_lower = 0, 0
    for characters in password:
        if characters.isupper():
            count_upper += 1
        if characters.islower():
            count_lower += 1
    is_password_good = True
    if len(password) <= 10:
        print "Password Is Too Weak, Must Be More Than 10 Characters Long!"
        is_password_good = False
    if set(database).intersection(password):
        print "Password Must Contain Alphanumeric Characters!"
        is_password_good = False
    if count_upper < 1 or count_lower < 1:
        print "Password Must Contain at Least One Uppercase and One Lowercase Character!"
        is_password_good = False
        create_user(database)
    print "Welcome! Username & Password Successfully Created!"
    return is_password_good
```

I want the create_user() function raw_input for passcode to return back to passcode if the user's password doesn't qualify on the above function; however, the create_user() function returns the passcode raw_input back to the user raw_input if the password doesn't work.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

```
def create_user(database):
    good_user = False
    good_pass = False
    while not good_user or not good_pass:
        user = raw_input("Enter a New Username: ")
        good_user = is_good_user(user)
        passcode = raw_input("Enter a New Password: ")
        good_pass = is_good_password(passcode)
        database[user] = passcode
        dump_data()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add another loop; you don't need to use flag variables either, just use `break` to end the loop when you have a good user or password:

```
while True:
    user = raw_input("Enter a New Username: ")
    if is_good_user(user):
        break
    print "That's not a good username, please try again"

while True:
    passcode = raw_input("Enter a New Password: ")
    if is_good_password(passcode):
        break
    print "That's not a good password, please try again"

database[user] = passcode
dump_data()
```

Comment: That's solid; however, the "user" variable is not recognized in database[user] = passcode since user variable is in another while loop. So what is the fix to this?

Comment: @MartianE: The scope of the `user` variable goes beyond the `while` block. This works, there is no need to fix that. `user` is *always* set, the loop only stops when it is.

Answer (score 0):

Did I understand you correctly?

```
def create_user(database):
  good_user = False
  good_pass = False
  while not good_user:
    user = raw_input("Enter a New Username: ")
    good_user = is_good_user(user)
  while not good_pass:
    passcode = raw_input("Enter a New Password: ")
    good_pass =  is_good_password(passcode)
  database[user] = passcode
  dump_data()
```

Comment: No, if the user enters a wrong password, then the loop goes back to the top and asks for a new username again, even though the username was fine.